# Handle null in Java null value not printing

Tags: java

```
String  phone = rs.getString("CCU_PHONE");
System.out.println("phone" + phone);
```

I am getting value for phone from a database and it is `null` hence it is not printing the value.

How do I handle the `null` and print the value in `System.out`?

Comment: so, it doesn't print "phonenull", just "phone" ? in that case, are you sure phone is null and not an empty String?

Comment: What do you mean "handle the null"? And if it's null, what value do you want to print?

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: i know the value of phone is null in database and i am sure about it,i want to print that in my Sys.out,if it is null then it have to print null

Comment: My SQL and i checked in my database the value is Null only.       Just i want to print it here

Comment: well, it would appear that your code is returning an empty String, not null, as result. maybe you've added somewhere in your code that null should return ""?
can you follow the code, debug and check step by step what value you return?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
 System.out.println("phone" +((phone!=null)?phone:" number not found !"));
```

Comment: if phone = "", this won't really help.

Comment: @Stultuske if you are not mistaken how `""` be a phone number? That validation should be there in insertion time.

Comment: have I said "" is a valid phone number? I merely stated that "" and null are not the same, so for phone = "", it should not print phonenull, but phone

Comment: @Stultuske then add that validation too.

Comment: Ruchira: it's already doing that, there's no additional validation needed for that

Answer (score 1):

Try writing yor database query like this,here if the field value is null it will print the whatever value that you specified as second paramater within the braces

For Oracle

```
select nvl(CCU_PHONE,'null') from tablename
```

For Mysql

```
select ifnull(CCU_PHONE,'null') from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for `NULL` before you print,

```
String  phone = rs.getString("CCU_PHONE");      

if (phone == null || phone.isEmpty())
    {
     System.out.println("NULL");
    }
    else
    {
    System.out.println("phone" + phone);
    }
```

Comment: Phhh. This should always be written as `"".equals(phone)` to avoid an NPE. Or - maybe better - it should be `if (phone == null || phone.isEmpty()) ...`. Last but not least: Handling an empty string the same as a null string is not the best idea.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose thanks for your suggestion . edited accordingly

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if your string is null or empty and based on that you can use if else to print

```
if (phone!= null && !phone.isEmpty()) {
   System.out.println("phone" + phone);
}
else
{
System.out.println("phonenull");
}
```

Comment: in what case is "" equal to null? it should print what it returns. but it appears, it's not returning what it should. the problem is not really related to the printing part, I guess.

Comment: @Stultuske Edited. I am going with general approach. Depending on Database constraints the phone can be null or it can be an empty string. So its better to check both conditions

Comment: sorry guys nothing worked still it is not printing the value of phone at all

Answer (score 0):

Reason: Whenever you try to access a variable whose value is `null`, it will always result into a `NullPointerException` which will abruptly stop the execution, so, it is always recommended that you should check for `null` before trying to access the value.

Comment: *Whenever you try to access a method or a field from within an object whose value is null, it will lead to NPE*

Comment: @TheLostMind : yeah, right, I agree, null can be assigned to fields and methods only

Answer (score 0):

You can check if string is blank or not before printing...

```
String  phone = rs.getString("CCU_PHONE");

if(phone == null || "".equals(phone)) { 
   // this will cover null and string of zero length.
   System.out.println("Phone is null or empty.");
} else {
   // if string is not blank or null.
   System.out.println("phone" + phone);
}
```

PS : you can use [StringUtils#isBlank()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.String%29) also, which will check null, zero length as well as blank spaced string also.

Comment: will print `phonenull` when phone is null. Please recheck your code.

Comment: @TheLostMind `"null"` as a string value or object `null` ? it will print `phonenull` when string value is `"null"`...

Comment: when phone is `null` , not `"null"`. It will still print `phonenull` . Indeed your code will print `phone is null` when phone is `""` i.e, empty.

Comment: @TheLostMind updated !! I think `StringUtils.isBlank()` is more precise to use in this cases...